# Passing keyword argument into formset that is extended from BaseFormSet

Tags: django, django-forms

I've had to create a custom formset to validate the results of my formset. I've simplified the validation for the purpose of this example.

**forms.py**

```
class BaseUserServiceFormSet(BaseFormSet): 

    def get_form_kwargs(self, index):
       kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(index)
       kwargs['queryset'] = index
       return kwargs


    def clean(self):    
        for form in self.forms:
             user_title = form.cleaned_data['user_title']
             if user_title == None:
                 self.add_error('user_title', "Please enter a title for this service.")
```

Within my views, I'm passing a queryset into the formset.

**views.py**

```
  UserServiceFormSet = modelformset_factory(UserService, form=UserServiceForm, formset=BaseUserServiceFormSet, extra=1, max_num=4, can_delete=True)
  formset = UserServiceFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, queryset=UserService.objects.filter(user=user, title__extra_service=1), prefix='first')
```

When I open my page, I get the following error:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'
```

I've tried adding the following to my BaseUserServiceFormSet (in **forms.py**), but then I start to get a bunch of errors that refer to the default values that are initialized within the BaseFormSet (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/forms/formsets/). In otherwords, with my code, I'm overwritting the default init of BaseFormSet, which breaks things.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = kwargs.pop('queryset')
```

What change would I have to make in order to pass my queryset into my formset as a kwarg?

Thank you!

Comment: you don't call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)`?

Comment: @Alasdair, thanks for your feedback. I'm using queryset correctly. It contains all the instances that the user is supposed to be able to edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `modelformset_factory`, you should be subclassing `BaseModelFormSet`.

```
class BaseUserServiceFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):    
    ...
```

You probably shouldn't do `queryset = kwargs.pop('queryset')` - that will prevent the queryset being passed if you call `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` later in the `__init__` method.

The `get_form_kwargs` is used to pass kwargs to the form, which isn't what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I'm now able to load the page, but when I click "Save", I get the following error: 'UserServiceFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'add_error'

Comment: You can call `form.error()` to add the error to the form. Or `raise forms.ValidationError()` which will add the error to the entire formset. However, you should probably move that `clean` method to the form class. You only need the `clean` method on the base formset class if you want to validate something across all the forms (e.g. make sure that there are no duplicate user titles).

Comment: Interesting... I'll try moving it to the Form. Thanks

Comment: You're right about using BaseModelFormSet, but putting the def clean() on my UserServiceForm is causing another error. The error claims that there is no cleaned_data for my other form that has always worked. This is a complex page with 1 form and 2 formsets that all get submitted upon the user clicking submit. I'll have to assume that this is a bug with django. I'll need to find a different route. Thanks though.

Comment: We're getting off topic for this question, but I think it's unlikely that you've uncovered a bug in the Django forms/formsets code.

Comment: That is fair. I'll try to look for the problem in my code. Thanks